# Solve for a complex number $z$ in $z[\sqrt{3}\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{4})]=w+1$ with $w=-2i$ quickly

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$z[\sqrt{3}\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{4})]=w+1 \Leftrightarrow \\
z[\sqrt{3}\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{4})]=1-2i \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{1-2i}{\sqrt{3}\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}{4})} \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{1-2i}{\sqrt{3}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)} \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{1-2i}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}i}\Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{1-2i}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}i}$$

$$z = \frac{1-2i}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}(1+i)} \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\frac{1-2i}{1+i} \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\frac{(1-2i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}\Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\frac{-1-3i}{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
z = \frac{(-2-6i)(-2\sqrt{6})}{(2\sqrt{6})(-2\sqrt{6})} \Leftrightarrow \\
\vdots  \\
z = -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}i$$

That took me a ridiculously long amount of time. Is there any quicker way of solving this? 
By the way, the answer has to be in the $x+yi$ form.

Comment: Hint: use exponential form

Comment: It may be useful to note that $$\frac1{r\operatorname{cis} t}=\frac1r\operatorname{cis}(-t)$$